# C# Dynamic Set DataRow

Tags: c#, cassia

I used cassia.dll for manage terminal servers and write simple program. I'll get List Property but not know how make dynamic add in Datarow.

DataTable use for Filtring.

```
 private void btn_GetTSServers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
        TSManager = new TerminalServicesManager();
        ITerminalServer ITS = TSManager.GetRemoteServer("localhost");
        ITS.Open();

        BSource = new BindingSource();
        DTable = new DataTable();

        Type t = ITS.GetSessions().First().GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] propinfo = t.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propinfo)
        {
            DTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
        }

        foreach(ITerminalServicesSession session in ITS.GetSessions())
        {
           DTable.Rows.Add(session.ServerName, .. .. . .. etc How make Dynamic?)   
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = DTable;
}
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = textBox1.Text;
        }
```

Comment: Whats the problem you're facing? Do you get any errors? Please extend your description, so we know, what exactly is the problem here, atleast I would have to guess.

Comment: How make without Listings "session.ServerName, .. .. . .. etc". I whant use dynamic list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like: (pseudo-code, not tested/optimized)

```
foreach(var session in ITS.GetSessions())
{
    Type t = session.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] propinfo = t.GetProperties();
    var list = new List<object>();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propinfo)
    {
        list.Add(prop.GetValue(session, null));
    }
    DTable.Rows.Add(list.ToArray());   
}
```